# How do I write a selector for only elements that have a "data-" attribute?

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, selector

I'm using JQuery 1.12.  How do I write a selector that will only apply to elements that have a "data-order" attribute defined?  I tried this

```
  $('[data-order!=""]').click ->
    console.log( $(this).html() )
```

but this seems to apply to the entire HTML document.  At least, the first "console.log" prints out everything from my HTML document, even though I don't have a "data-order" attribute defined at my <html> root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close:

```
$('[data-order]').click ->
    console.log( $(this).html() )
```